# Why did Dropzone image upload with multiple form inputs not working

Tags: jquery, html, dropzone

'm developing one website for a real-estate agency. I have a html form that is used to submit property details, There is multiple form inputs and also I need to upload multiple property images using Dropzone JS multiple image upload.

Here I'm validating form inputs using jQuery Validation library. Validation works perfect and data Is being to posted to php file called submit_property_data.php. But when I implement the Dropzone JS image upload its not working.

property-submit.js

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("#notification-property").hide();

  /* handling form validation */
  $("#property-form").validate({
    rules: {
      prop_title: "required",
      prop_price: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
        },
      prop_area: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
      },
      prop_address: "required",
      prop_message: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 2000
      },
      prop_owner_name: "required",
      prop_owner_email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      prop_owner_phone: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      'prop_title': {
        required: "Please enter title for your property"
      },
      prop_price: {
        required: "Please enter price of your property",
        digits: "Please enter price in digits (AED)"
      },
      prop_area: "Please enter Sqft of your property",
      prop_address: "Please enter address of your property",
      prop_message: {
        required: "Please enter detailed Information",
        minlength: "Please enter something about your property in 50 - 20000 characters",
        maxlength: "Please enter something about your property in 50 - 20000 characters"
      },

            prop_owner_name: "Please enter your name",
            prop_owner_email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                email: "Please enter valid email address"

            },
            prop_owner_phone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number",
                digits: "Please enter valid phone number"

            },
    },
    submitHandler: submitPropertyForm
  });

  /* Handling login functionality */
  function submitPropertyForm() {
    var data = $("#property-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'submit_property_data.php',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#submit-button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; Submiting ...');
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == "ok") {
          console.log(1);
          document.getElementById("property-form").reset();
          $("#notification-property").html('<b> ' + response + ' !</b>').show();
          //setTimeout(' window.location.href = "dashboard.php"; ',4000);
        } else {
          $("#notification-property").fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $("#notification-property").html('<b>' + response + ' !</b>').fadeOut();
            $("#submit-button").html('&nbsp; Send');
          });
        }
      },
            complete:function(){
                                             $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('form').offset().top}, 'slow');
                                     }
    });
    return false;
  }

    $("#submit-button").bind('click', function() {
      if ( $("#property-form").valid() ) {
          submitPropertyForm();
      } else {
          console.log('form invalid');
      }
  })


        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $(function () {
                $("div#myDropzone").dropzone({

                        url: 'submit_property_data.php',
                        addRemoveLinks: true,
                        maxFiles:11,
                        uploadMultiple: true,
                        autoProcessQueue: false,
                        parallelUploads: 10,

                        init: function () {

                                var myDropzone = this;

                                // Update selector to match your button
                                $("#submit-button").click(function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                                });


                                this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
                                        // Append all form inputs to the formData Dropzone will POST
                                        var data = $('#property-form').serializeArray();
                                        $.each(data, function(key, el) {
                                                formData.append(el.name, el.value);
                                        });
                                });

                                    this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                                            alert(responseText);
                                    });

                            },


                });
        });


});
```

HTML File (submit_property.php)

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

!-- Submit Property start -->
<div class="content-area-7 submit-property">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

          <!--      <div id="error_message" class="notification-box"></div> -->





            </div>
            <div id="notification-property" class="notification-box">sd</div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="submit-address">
                    <form name = "property-form" method="post" id="property-form">
                        <div class="main-title-2">
                            <h1><span>Tell Me</span> Something About Your Property</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="search-contents-sidebar mb-30">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Property Title</label>

                                <input class="input-text" name="prop_title" id="prop_title" placeholder="Property Title">

                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Status</label>
                                        <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="prop_status" name="prop_status">
                                            <option value="Sale">For Sale</option>
                                            <option value="Rent">For Rent</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Type</label>
                                        <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="prop_title" name="prop_type">
                                            <option value="Modern">Modern</option>
                                            <option value="Traditional">Traditional</option>
                                            <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>

                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Price (Dirham)</label>
                                        <input class="input-text" name="prop_price" id="prop_price" placeholder="AED">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Sqft</label>
                                        <input class="input-text" name="prop_area" id="prop_area" placeholder="SqFt">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Bed Rooms</label>
                                        <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="prop_rooms" id="prop_rooms">

                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                            <option value="5">5</option>

                                        </select>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Bathroom</label>
                                        <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                                            <option>1</option>
                                            <option>2</option>
                                            <option>3</option>
                                            <option>4</option>
                                            <option>5</option>
                                            <option>6</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="main-title-2">
                            <h1><span>Location</span></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-30 ">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Address</label>
                                    <input class="input-text" id="prop_address" name="prop_address"  placeholder="Address">
                                </div>

                            </div>



                        </div>

                        <div class="main-title-2">
                        <h1><span>Upload</span> Photos Of Villa </h1>
                        </div>

                        <div id="myDropzone" class="dropzone dropzone-design mb-10">
                          <div class="dz-default dz-message" data=""><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
                                                </div>

                        <div class="main-title-2">
                            <h1><span>Detailed</span> Information</h1>
                        </div>



                        <div class="row mb-30">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="input-text" id="prop_message" name="prop_message" placeholder="Detailed Information"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="row mb-30">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Building Age <span>(optional)</span></label>
                                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="years">
                                        <option>0-1 Years</option>
                                        <option>0-5 Years</option>
                                        <option>0-10 Years</option>
                                        <option>0-20 Years</option>
                                        <option>0-40 Years</option>
                                        <option>40+Years</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Bedrooms (optional)</label>
                                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>
                                        <option>5</option>
                                        <option>6</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Bathrooms (optional)</label>
                                    <select class="selectpicker search-fields" name="1">
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>
                                        <option>5</option>
                                        <option>6</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <label class="margin-t-10">Features (optional)</label>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                            <input id="opt_parking" name="opt_parking" value="1" type="checkbox">
                                            <label for="checkbox1">
                                                Free Parking
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                            <input id="opt_air_condition" name="opt_air_condition" value="1" type="checkbox">
                                            <label for="checkbox2">
                                                Air Condition
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                            <input id="opt_seat" name="opt_seat" value="1" type="checkbox">
                                            <label for="checkbox3">
                                                Places to seat
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                            <input id="opt_swimming" name="opt_swimming" value="1" type="checkbox">
                                            <label for="checkbox4">
                                                Swimming Pool
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                            <input id="opt_laundary" name="opt_laundary" value="1" type="checkbox">
                                            <label for="checkbox5">
                                                Laundry Room
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                            <input id="opt_window_covering" name="opt_window_covering" value="1" type="checkbox">
                                            <label for="checkbox6">
                                                Window Covering
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                            <input id="opt_parking" name="opt_parking" value="1" type="checkbox">
                                            <label for="checkbox7">
                                                Central Heating
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                            <input id="checkbox8" type="checkbox">
                                            <label for="checkbox8">
                                                Alarm
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->
                        <div class="main-title-2">
                            <h1><span>Contact</span> Details</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Name</label>
                                    <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_name" id="prop_owner_name" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_email" id="prop_owner_email" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Contact No</label>
                                    <input class="input-text" name="prop_owner_phone" id="prop_owner_phone" placeholder="Phone">
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button type="button" name="submit-button" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="property-submit.js"></script>
<script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>

</html>
```

PHP File (submit_property_data.php)

```
<?php
echo "ok";
require_once("functions.php");


$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$storeFolder = 'villas-images';
$encpt_data = rand(1000,5000);

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

   $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3

   $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

   $targetFile =  $targetPath.$_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

   if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile))
   {

     echo '<b>Success</b>';


   }
}
?>
```

dropzone not working with the form

What I actually need ?

I need to validate the form inputs first & upload the images once the form is valid also I need to post all the inputs to my php file called submit_property_data.php

Also I need the image inputs to store into my database.

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone requires `action` attribute which you must include it in your `<div id="myDropzone" class="dropzone dropzone-design mb-10">` it only works when you redirect a given file to a certain page.

But as `<div>` tag does not respond to `action` attribute try to use form tag for all the above procedure mentioned.